# C# and MS Access 2010 case-sensitive SELECT

Tags: c#, .net, sql, select, ms-access-2010

I've a little question about the select statement with Access database.
I want to perform this in a C#/.NET project:

```
var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM COMPONENT WHERE TAGNAME = '" + tagName + "'");
```

For example:

I have a tagName equal to "TEST" and another with "Test". But, right now I retrieve both uppercase and lowercase TagNames.
I want to retrieved only lowercase **OR** uppercase values..

How should I do that? Is there a solution such as Char.IsUpper in Access ?

Thanks in advance, I hope I was clear.

Ars_n

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,It may help you

```
var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM COMPONENT WHERE TAGNAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS= '" + tagName + "'"");
```

Comment: I don't believe `COLLATE` works in Access 2016. Came looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

To do a case-sensitive SELECT from an Access database you need to use the `StrComp()` function, documented [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx).

In your case, your code should look something like this:

```
int vbBinaryCompare = 0;
var cmd = new OdbcCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;  // con is an open OdbcConnection
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = 
        "SELECT * FROM COMPONENT " +
        "WHERE StrComp([TAGNAME], ?, ?) = 0";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", tagName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", vbBinaryCompare);
var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
```